# Relying on the OU for some products

Tags: kashrut-kosher

There are those who do not rely on the OU's kosher certification for every product, because they do not agree with certain leniencies the OU relies on.

Are there products or types of products certified by the OU that everyone accepts, even people who are generally stringent and do not rely on the Oy for every product?

Comment: Yes. All the base products that the "haimishe" hashgachos allow to be used as ingredients in the products under their watch:)

Comment: Can you clarify your question a little. I am Havong a hard time understanding what you're asking. Are you asking if there are OU products that everyone, no matter how strict, will use?

Comment: @Menachem. Yes. Exactly. Thank you for saying it more clearly.

Comment: I rewrote the question to try and make it more clear. If it wasn't what you were trying to ask then revert or further edit the question

Answer (score 2):

There are diverse reasons why an OU may be an insufficient indication of *kashruth* for many kosher consumers. For example, for those who keep the prohibition of *chodosh*, while OU-certified products containing one of the 5 types of *dagan* may be problematic,  those without grain might be fine. Also, for those who do not hold of Rav Moshe Feinstein's leniency regarding mass-produced milk, nondairy products might not be an issue. Similarly, some consumers may only avoid meat or wine handled by messianic Lubavitchers,  but rely on the OU for products not containing these ingredients.